# Match files names in a directory with names in a dataframe column - Paste matched row as columns in the matched file

Tags: r, directory, string-matching

I have 100 files.txt in a folder.

Those filenames.txt are written identically into column1 rows of a R dataframe.

The files.txt are less than the dataframe column1 rows! Meaning that not all the rows of column1 will be matched!

What I would like to do :

If the filename match column1 name, then, insert names of column 2 and 3 on the same row (R dataframe), this as columns in the file.txt.

**Example**

```
Name   Family  Subfamily
marc    A        B
Jaco    C        D
```

```
marc.txt   
Jaco.txt
```

Out-put files.txt containing the new columns family and subfamily.

marc.txt

```
column1 column2 .....  Family Subfamily 
.....   ......  .....    A     B
.....    .....  .....    A     B
.....    .....  ......   A     B
```

jaco.txt

```
column1 column2 .....  Family Subfamily 
.....   ......  .....    C     D
.....    .....  .....    C     D
.....    .....   ....    C     D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: created check to see if file exists

Something like this should work:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("marc", "Jaco"),
                  Family = c("A.", "C"),
                  Subfamily = c("B", "D"))

files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  if (!paste0(df1[i,1], ".txt") %in% files) {
    next()
  }
  dfi <- read.csv(paste0(df1[i,1], ".txt"))
  dfi <- cbind(dfi, df1[i,-1])
  write.csv(dfi, paste0(df1[i,1], ".txt"))
}
```

Just need to replace the table names

Comment: Thank you for your help! the problem is that it searches to match the first name on the list, but the first name of the dataframe it is not between the files. I need a command saying to do this work only on the files that are indeed found in the directory.. it doesn't mean all the name of the column 1 of the dataframe will be matched then. Error: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'filename1.txt': No such file or directory @Wietse de Vries

Comment: @Myke created a check that checks for every iteration if the file exists and if it doesn't the code will skip to the next `i`